# The constructor JsonPrimitive(Object) is not visible

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am trying to wrapp an arrayList as Json string to send it to the Server with the `Gson` library but I am getting this error `The constructor JsonPrimitive(Object) is not visible`.

How can I fix that?

I appreciate any help.

SelectedRoute class:

```
public class SelectedRoute {

    ArrayList<Integer> selected;

    public SelectedRoute(ArrayList<Integer> selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(ArrayList<Integer> selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }


}
```

SelectedRouteSerializer class:

```
   public class SelectedRouteSerializer implements JsonSerializer<SelectedRoute>{

        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(SelectedRoute select, Type arg1,
                JsonSerializationContext arg2) {
            JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
              //The error is here.
            result.add("selected", new JsonPrimitive(select.getSelected()));


            return result;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Your current question has nothing to do with the title. Please don't drastically alter your question. Just add any additional information required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [JSON primitive](http://json.org/) is any of

```
string
number
object
array
true
false
null
```

and these are represented with Gson's `JsonPrimitve` with four constructors: one for `Boolean`, one for `String`, one for `Number`, and one for `Character` (a one character `String`). `JsonPrimitive` has a package private constructor which could accept your `ArrayList` value but, being package private, it is not accessible to your code.

A Java `ArrayList` cannot be represented as a JSON primitive. It should be a JSON array.

---

You've now edited your question, but here's a sample for building up a `JsonObject` directly

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
for (Integer value : arrayList) {
    jsonArray.add(new JsonPrimitive(value));
}
jsonObject.add("selected", jsonArray);
```

Comment: Is there any  way to wrapp the arrayList<Integer> as json string?

Comment: @MrPencil Please clarify how you expect it to be represented in the JSON.

Comment: like this {"selected": [1,3,4] } I think I made a circuit.

Comment: Why are you using a custom serializer for that? Given the format of your `SelectedRoute` class, that's how Gson will serialize your object by default. `new Gson().toJson(someSelectedRoute);`.

Comment: I tested it but  I am getting it like this [1,3,4] without `selected` Is not it possibale to get the key too?

Comment: @MrPencil Please edit your question and add a complete and reproducible example that generates that JSON.

Comment: I dont have the code to generate the JSON jsut what I had before  I have edited my question I hope that help.

Comment: @MrPencil In your new example, you're serialized an `ArrayList` directly. In your previous example, I was suggesting you serialize the `SelectedRoute`. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: I want to get a key and the value as json string whatever how with whether with `Selectedroute` class or without it. I have deleted the other part but I can added them again if you like

Comment: If you create a POJO type `Selectedroute` with a field named `selected` of type `ArrayList`, create an instance, set its `selected` value, and serialize it, you'll get the JSON `{"selected": [1,3,4] }`. Alternatively, see my edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79368/discussion-between-mrpencil-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: You have not used the gson object in your simple?

Comment: @MrPencil Oh, yeah, you don't need it. I'll remove it.